# NServiceBus consume 3rd party xml

Tags: nservicebus

All, can anyone provide me some guidance on allowing NServiceBus to consume XML messages off a queue that were not created by NServiceBus.  I am trying to integrate with a 3rd party system that drops XML messages to a queue.  I have VERY little control over the XML the 3rd party produces.

I have tried wrapping their XML with the -Messages/- tag and I can get the message to hit the right handler, but many of the fields (especially in child classes) just deserialize to null.  The 3rd party produces several "types" of messages but in all cases the XML is reasonably simple.

I'm trying to avoid writing an adapter that just reads XML and drops messages on the bus.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The key lies in how you generate the message classes. If you can, you should get the XSD schemas from the third party that represent the XMLs they are sending you.

Then you can generate classes off the schemas using xsd.exe which will pretty much guarantee clean de-serialisation from XML to type.

If you can't get the schemas then you can again use xsd.exe to infer the schemas from the messages. However this method is not particularly fail-safe, and will expose you negatively to anything unexpected the message which does not conform to your inferred schema.

Comment: Yea,  I tried using xsd.exe to infer the schema and then generate the class...  I got pretty close that way but still end up with a lot of child classes where all the properties are NULL ... when the xml clearly has values.

Comment: Can you not get the third party to give you a schema?

Answer (score 0):

The serialization in NSB is abstracted so you could write your own serializer based on that format.  You can then tell NSB to use your serializer instead of one of the built in ones.

Comment: using the plain .Net System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer I can deserialize the xml just fine..  which makes me wonder 2 things...  can I just plug this one in (with ease) and also why is the nsb one so far off on the deserialization when it's a simple document format...  I must be doing something wrong ?

Comment: The serializer it uses is custom to accomodate interfaces(XSD.exe doesn't do this).  Maybe you should just try using the provided schema tool, I'm just not sure it produces classes.  I'd give that a try.